# Ad-hoc network disconnecting when not using web

Tags: ethernet, wireless-access-point, ad-hoc-network

I am at university and I have a desktop computer and several mobile devices, however only a wired Ethernet connection is provided in my room. I want to use an ad-hoc network to share my internet connection with my other devices however I have a problem with it keep dropping out.

I am sharing the connection from my desktop which is plugged into the Ethernet, and has a wireless card installed. I want to share the connection over wireless however when my desktop is not accessing the internet, all my devices disconnect from the network. I have unchecked the "Turn off this device to save power when not in use" however the problem persists. What could possibly be causing this to happen? Also, we aren't allowed routers otherwise we get a fine of £70..

Thanks

Comment: tried using Connectify? is a hell lot stable, i use it to share a dongle internet with 2 computers and an android phone flawlessly. link: http://www.connectify.me/

Comment: @Znau I should have mentioned, I have tried third party software like Connectify however I get the same issue.